# Masking a DataFrame on multiple column conditions - inside a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to mask my dataframe conditional on multiple columns inside a loop. I am trying to do something like this:

```
dfs = []
val_dict = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}
for i in range(4):
    items = [val_dict[i] for i in range(i+1)]
    df_ = df[(df['0'] == items[0]) & (df['1'] == items[1]) & ... ]
    dfs.append(df_)
```

Please note that the second condition I wrote above would not exist for the first iteration of the loop because there would be no items[1] element.

Here is a sample dataframe you are welcome to test on:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': ['a']*3 + ['b']*3 + ['c']*3,
                   '1': ['a']*3 + ['b']*6,
                   '2': ['b']*4 + ['c']*5,
                   '3': ['c']*5 + ['d']*4})
```

The only solution I have come up with uses `eval` which I would like very much to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subset your DataFrame to include *only the columns you want to use for comparison* (as you have done in your example) and the keys in your `val_dict` are the same as the columns you want to compare, then you can get Pandas to do this for you.

Making a slight modification to your `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['a']*3 + ['b']*3 + ['c']*3,
                   1: ['a']*3 + ['d']*6,
                   2: ['b']*4 + ['c']*5,
                   3: ['c']*5 + ['a']*4})
```

You can now accomplish what you want by the following

```
dfs = []
val_dict = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}
val_series = pd.Series(val_dict)

for i in range(4):
    mask = (df == val_series).all(axis=1)
    dfs.append(df[mask])
```

**EDIT**
I am leaving my original solution even though it addresses a different problem than OP intended to solve.  The intended problem can be solved by the following:

```
mask = True
for key in range(4):
    mask &= df[key] == val_dict[key]
    dfs.append(df[mask])
```

Again, this is using the modified `df` used earlier in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving my problem a go @JaminSore, but this doesn't do what I am trying to accomplish. The idea that I mask `df[(df['0'] == items[0])]` for the first loop, `df[(df['0'] == items[0]) & (df['1'] == items[1])]` for the 2nd,  `df[(df['0'] == items[0]) & (df['1'] == items[1]) & (df['2'] == items[2])]` for the 3rd, etc... Your loop has no i dependence inside so it does the same thing every time!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you were going for. See my edit.

Comment: Brilliant! The key insight here is remembering that the mask is a Series object and then defining a variable to hold it

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my `eval` solution.

```
for i in range(4):
    items = [val_dict[i] for i in range(i+1)]
    df_ = eval('df[(' + ') & ('.join(['df["'+str(j)+'"] == items['+str(j)+']' for j in range(i+1)]) + ')]')
    dfs.append(df_)
```

It works... but so ugly :(