# pandas: Create new column by comparing DataFrame rows with columns of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have `df1`:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'alligator_apple': range(1, 11),
                  'barbadine': range(11, 21),
                  'capulin_cherry': range(21, 31)})

   alligator_apple  barbadine  capulin_cherry
0                1         11              21
1                2         12              22
2                3         13              23
3                4         14              24
4                5         15              25
5                6         16              26
6                7         17              27
7                8         18              28
8                9         19              29
9               10         20              30
```

And a `df2`:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'alligator_apple': [6, 7, 15, 5],
                  'barbadine': [3, 19, 25, 12],
                  'capulin_cherry': [1, 9, 15, 27]})

   alligator_apple  barbadine  capulin_cherry
0                6          3               1
1                7         19               9
2               15         25              15
3                5         12              27
```

I'm looking for a way to create a new column in `df2` that gets number of rows based on a condition where all columns in `df1` has values greater than their counterparts in `df2` for each row. For example:

```
   alligator_apple  barbadine  capulin_cherry  greater
0                6          3               1       4
1                7         19               9       1
2               15         25              15       0
3                5         12              27       3
```

To elaborate, at row 0 of `df2`, `df1.alligator_apple` has  4 rows which values are higher than `df2.alligator_apple` with the value of 6. `df1.barbadine` has 10 rows which values are higher than `df2.barbadine` with value of 3, while similarly `df1.capulin_cherry` has 10 rows.

Finally, apply an 'and' condition to all aforementioned conditions to get the number '4' of `df2.greater` of first row. Repeat for the rest of rows in `df2`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
df2['greater'] = df2.apply(
    lambda row: 
    (df1['alligator_apple'] > row['alligator_apple']) & 
    (df1['barbadine'] > row['barbadine']) & 
    (df1['capulin_cherry'] > row['capulin_cherry']), 
    axis=1,
).sum(axis=1)

print(df2)
```

output:

```
   alligator_apple  barbadine  capulin_cherry  greater
0                6          3               1        4
1                7         19               9        1
2               15         25              15        0
3                5         12              27        3
```

Edit: if you want to generalize and apply this logic for a given column set, we can use `functools.reduce` together with `operator.and_`:

```
import functools
import operator

columns = ['alligator_apple', 'barbadine', 'capulin_cherry']

df2['greater'] = df2.apply(
    lambda row: functools.reduce(
        operator.and_, 
        (df1[column] > row[column] for column in columns),
    ), 
    axis=1,
).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a general solution to this that should work well.

```py
def gt_mask(row,df):
    mask = True
    for key,val in row.items():
        mask &= df[key] > val
    return len(df[mask])

df2['greater'] = df2.apply(gt_mask,df=df1,axis=1)
```

Output df2

```py
,alligator_apple,barbadine,capulin_cherry,greater
0,6,3,1,4
1,7,19,9,1
2,15,25,15,0
3,5,12,27,3
```

This creates a mask, iterating through the key/val pairs for a given row.

Edit this answer was a big help: [Masking a DataFrame on multiple column conditions - inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895067/masking-a-dataframe-on-multiple-column-conditions-inside-a-loop)